# Perl: ошибка сегментации при параллельном подключении по SSH

Tags: perl, ssh, распараллеливание

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use threads;
use Net::SSH::Perl;

    sub thread_routine {
        if ($i<=9) {
            $server = 's0'. $i;
        }
        else {
            $server = 's'. $i;
        }

        printf ( "Подключаемся к $server\n");
        my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl ->new($server);
            $ssh->login("user", "xxx");
        $cmd = 'df -k';
        my ($out, $err, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
        print ( "$out");
        return $i;
    }
foreach $i (1..10) {
push @threads,threads->create('thread_routine',$i);
}
foreach $thread (@threads) {
$thread->join();
}
```

Подключаемся к s01

Подключаемся к s02

Подключаемся к s03

Подключаемся к s04

...

Подключаемся к s10

Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)

Answer (score 4):

Переписала код, теперь хосты берутся из файла. Вместо модуля threads использую Parallel::ForkManager. Работает, ошибки сегментации не возникает

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $max_procs = 3;
my @hosts;
my $timeout = 30;
my $input = shift;
die "Usage: $0 FILE\n" if ! $input;
open (INPUT, $input) || die "Can't read '$input': $!\n";
while (<INPUT>) {
    chomp ($_);
    my $line = $_;
    push @hosts, $line;
}
close INPUT;
my $pm =  new Parallel::ForkManager($max_procs);

foreach my $host (@hosts) {
    my $pid = $pm->start() and next;
    print "$host \n";
    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl ->new("$host");
    $ssh->login("user", "xxx");
    my $cmd = 'w';
    my($out, $err, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
    print "$out \n";
    $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```